# .closest() not working on jquery when applied to on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this

```
<table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Downpayment (%)</th>
        <th>Downpayment (₱)</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Payment Period (Months)</th>
        <th>MA 1 - XX</th>
        <th>MA 1 - XX (VAT)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dp-perce" data-perce="0">0%</td>
        <td class="dp-peso"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dp-perce" data-perce="15">15%</td>
        <td class="dp-peso"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dp-perce" data-perce="30">30%</td>
        <td class="dp-peso"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dp-perce" data-perce="50">50%</td>
        <td class="dp-peso"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="dp-perce" data-perce="95">95%</td>
        <td class="dp-peso"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

whenever I use closest(), it is always returning null. what seems to be the problem?
here is my jquery:

```
<script>
     $('#unit-type').on('change', function() {
       $('.dp-peso').each(function(){
           var percentage = $(this).closest('td').find('.dp-perce').data('perce');
           $(this).text(percentage);
       });
    });
   </script>
```

what this script is doing is to get the value of data-attribute of the closest dp-perce then display to class name dp-peso.

please let me know the bug. I've been stuck here for a long time/

Comment: I also have a select with an id of unit-type.

Comment: There is no `'td .dp-perce` in your markup. You probably mean `.closest('tr')`

Comment: `.dp-peso` is a `<td>` element. `.closest()` traverses UP the DOM and `find('.dp-perce')` is a sibling, so of course it wont find it. Did you want `.prev()` instead of `.closest()`?

Comment: I was looking for the closest element to dp-peso with a class of dp-perce and get its data attribute. that's why I decided to use. closest().

Comment: I think. prev() gets the previous element from the same class name

Comment: Another is `$(this).siblings('.dp-perce')`

Comment: @Blitzkriegfest You are incorrect regarding what both prev() and closest() do. The descriptions in the docs would be a good place to start

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for this one! .siblings() worked for me.